# Existe alguma forma de criar uma conta moip pela api do moip?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de *marketplace* e cada vendedor precisa ter uma conta MOIP para receber as vendas.

Como esses vendedores são bem leigos pensei em automatizar isso para que eles não precisem criar uma conta MOIP, sendo esta criada automaticamente pelo sistema.

É possível fazer isso via API? Ou a única forma é montar via CURL?

Comment: Acessa o link abaixo e de uma analisada na parte que diz: "_Cadastro Co-branded" que diz como enviar os dados do lojista do Marketplace diretamente ao Moip. [_Cadastro Co-branded](https://labs.moip.com.br/integracao/integracao-de-marketplaces/)

Answer (score 1):

O Moip possui uma API para cadastro, chamado de "**Cadastro co-branded**" voltado para plataformas Marketplaces, ele pode facilitar a entrada do cliente no Moip, onde você pode enviar os dados do cliente já salvo em sua base ao Moip, e redirecionando o cliente ao Moip apenas para que ele cadastre uma senha pessoal.

Documentação em PDF: https://labs.moip.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/IntegracaoAPI-Cadastro-Integrado.pdf

Link para referência completa de soluções para Marketplace: https://labs.moip.com.br/integracao/integracao-de-marketplaces/

Essas APIs fazem parte da plataforma **v1 do Moip**, onde você se comunica com dados em **XML**.

Ainda esse ano o Moip deve lançar suas novas APIs para marketplace e disponibilizar uma nova forma de cadastro por API.

Answer (score 0):

Lembrando que a **Moip** virou **Wirecard**. Sim é possível criar conta como marketplace.

Veja um exemplo abaixo de como criar conta transparente:

```
$account = $moip->accounts()
    ->setName('Fulano')
  ->setLastName('De Tal')
  ->setEmail('fulano@email2.com')
  ->setIdentityDocument('4737283560', 'SSP', '2015-06-23')
  ->setBirthDate('1988-12-30')
  ->setTaxDocument('16262131000')
  ->setType('MERCHANT')
  ->setTransparentAccount(true)
  ->setPhone(11, 66778899, 55)
  ->addAlternativePhone(11, 66448899, 55)
  ->addAddress('Rua de teste', 123, 'Bairro', 'Sao Paulo', 'SP', '01234567', 'Apt. 23', 'BRA')
  ->setCompanyName('Empresa Teste', 'Teste Empresa ME')
  ->setCompanyOpeningDate('2011-01-01')
  ->setCompanyPhone(11, 66558899, 55)
  ->setCompanyTaxDocument('69086878000198')
  ->setCompanyAddress('Rua de teste 2', 123, 'Bairro Teste', 'Sao Paulo', 'SP', '01234567', 'Apt. 23', 'BRA')
  ->setCompanyMainActivity('82.91-1/00', 'Atividades de cobranças e informações cadastrais')
  ->create();
```

Biblioteca: [moip-sdk-php](https://github.com/wirecardBrasil/moip-sdk-php)